# How to list line items along with Zoho books Sales orders list through Zoho Books API?

Tags: zoho, zohobooks

When I listing the Zoho Books sales order via Zoho Books API, The line_items of the sales order is not returning.
Is there any way to get the line items along with the sales order list via API?
Otherwise, I have to request each sales order to get the line items of that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you fetch the list of sales orders then in response line items detail not be there. you need to fetch individual sales order then you will get all details.